# Operand should contain 1 column(s) in left join

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1241

Can you please help me into this?

```
mysql> select * from db.tblname1 
       left join db.tblname2 
       on(tblname1.id=tblname2.id,tblname1.`datetime`=tblname2.`datetime`)
       limit 1 into outfile '/backup/saved-export/archive_master_merge1.sql';
```

> ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
>       mysql>

Answer (score 3):

You miss out the operand 'AND'

```
tblname1.id=tblname2.id AND tblname1.`datetime`=tblname2.`datetime`
```